# Lightning Web Component (LWC) - Dynamically configure child components (Like "Add Component(s) Here" in Tabs/Accordion)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-app-builder

I'm doing some research on modular Lightning Web Component. The idea is to have developers create LWC and admins can drag/drop to configure components.

With the standard Tabs/Accordion component (Shown below), it allows child components to be configured dynamically. Is there a way we can implement the same in LWC?

According to what I found so far it seems not possible in LWC - The workaround is somehow around using `<slot>` but that's still coding task.

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, it seems like you're trying to recreate what is already in App Builder (which you tagged). Perhaps I'm just not understanding the question?

Comment: @pchittum he probably means, if he added a component with slot in app-builder, he should be able to add another component in that parent component from app builder.

Like the way we can add tab component and in tab component add our custom component

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yes I wanted to confirm if we can ever do that. The App Builder is Page -> Add Component and what I'm wondering is Component - Add Component.

Answer (score 3):

It seems it is still not possible with either LWC or Aura. There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lLJlQAM) present for this you can upvote it.

Comment: Thanks - After this post I did more research on Custom Page Template (Essentially an Aura Component accepting Aura.Component[]), but that can only be used at Lightning Page level.

Comment: As someone mentioned in that IdeaExchange link, it IS possible to do this in LWR sites, but still not in Lightning Experience. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_layout.htm