# I want to create a Lightning Web Component that can contain components within itself (not hard coded) like the Tabs or Accordion component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-app-builder

What I am asking is similar to  [this question from 2019](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279556/lightning-web-component-lwc-dynamically-configure-child-components-like-ad). I want to create a static layout and the Admin/user can simply drag and drop components into this layout. Any methods I've seen so far need the child component to be present in the code of the parent. When I look at the [code for the Accordion](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/accordion/accordion.html) It isn't clear how it is being done. I want to know if it is possible to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways, but the way the [Accordion](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/accordion/accordion.html#L9) is doing is through [Slots](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots):

> A slot (`<slot></slot>`) is a placeholder for markup that a parent component passes into a component’s body.

The trick is that you can only do this under your own namespace for now unless you enable Lightning Web Security as mentioned in [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/378441/45578).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any documentation on how to achieve this I can refer to? any documentation about any method to achieve this would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Sandeep, yes, the documentation on Slots from [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots): shows an example of how to create and use either one slot, or multiple ones.